# Why does this python code conflict with itself?

Tags: python

When I try to run

```
import csv
import sys
import operator

fieldnames = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
surveyfile = open("source.csv", "r")
left_file = open("left.csv",'wb')
right_file = open("right.csv",'wb')


left_reader = csv.DictReader(surveyfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=",")
left_writer = csv.DictWriter(left_file, fieldnames, delimiter=",")
sortedlefts = sorted(left_reader,key=lambda x:float(x["B"]))

right_reader = csv.DictReader(surveyfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=",")
right_writer = csv.DictWriter(right_file, fieldnames, delimiter=",")
sortedrights = sorted(right_reader,key=lambda x:float(x["B"]), reverse=True)

for row in sortedlefts:
    if row["E"] == "l":
        left_writer.writerow(row)


for row in sortedrights:
    if row["E"] == "r":
        right_writer.writerow(row)
```

Nothing happens in the "right.csv" file.  But if I take everything that has to do with making the right.csv file out and put it into a different program, it works fine.  Do I need to end that for loop?  Is it some problem with using the same reader for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input file is likely exhausted, so yes it has to do with re-using the `reader` instance.

Not sure *why* you expect the `reader` object to magically know when it's supposed to re-deliver the data.

You need to be more explicit about this, I would simply recommend re-creating the reader as needed.

Comment: I changed the code in the question to use two different readers, but it still doesn't work.  I'm sorry, I've never really programmed before - I'm not sure how to be "more explicit".

Comment: @user1879422 What Unwind meant is that the `file` itself is exhausted (i.e. there's nothing left to read because `left_reader` read everything already). Close the file and open it again, or return to its beginning using `surveyfile.seek()`.

Comment: Wow, 3 responses in 15 minutes - you guys are awesome!!  I put a surveyfile.seek(0,0) in between the two readers and it works perfect.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

While it is indeed an issue with `reader` being exhausted. You can create a single for loop combined with some `itertools` help to fix this.

```
import itertools

left_reader, right_reader = itertools.tee(reader)

sortedlefts = sorted(left_reader,key=lambda x:float(x["B"]))
sortedrights = sorted(right_reader,key=lambda x:float(x["B"]), reverse=True)

for left, right in itertools.izip(sortedlefts, sortedrights):
    if left['E'] == 'l':
        left_writer.writerow(left)
    if right['E'] == 'r':
        right_writer.writerow(right)
```

Comment: This is probably the best way to do things, but it all seems way over my head.  It said itertools is not defined.  I don't even know what that is, lol.  I'll go look into it, and see if I can work your response in.  Definitely seems like the more elegant way of doing things.

Comment: @user1879422 A sorry, try doing an `import itertools` at the top of your file. These are the documentation links for the two functions I used from `itertools`. [tee](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) and [izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip).